# Server side rendering doesn't work with Axios withCredentials

Tags: next.js, axios, laravel-sanctum

I've an application with Laravel as backend and NextJs 13 (app router) as frontend. I'm using Sanctum in laravel for login and when the user is logged laravel send 2 cookies, one is httpOnly and another is a client cookie as we can see in the image

[image]

In NextJs is working as expected when I call the endpoints to Laravel because I'm using Axios and I set withCredentials where the cookies is sent automatically in each request.

Axios:

```
function createHttpClient(baseURL) {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
}
```

and the request has both cookies:

[image]

The problem I have is in NextJs with server side rendering, I have a page where in this case I need to get the data as static site generation

```
export default async function Page() {
  const response = await CategoryService.getAll();
  const categories = response.data.data;

  return (
    <CategoryView categories={categories} />
  )
}
```

the problem here is that the cookies are not sent, so the response is Unauthorize

```
response: {
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      server: 'nginx/1.21.6',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close',
      'x-powered-by': 'PHP/8.1.2',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, private',
      date: 'Sat, 09 Sep 2023 13:21:49 GMT',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, lang',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'set-cookie': [Array]
    },
```

I don't know how to add the cookies in server side rendering in next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the normal behaviour. Your cookies is set in browser. Remember, Next.js SSR is happening on server. Server doesn't have access to your browser cookies automatically. What you need to do is manually pass the cookie to your `axios` from header

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
```

Then in your function you can get do `cookies().get(KEY_NAME)` & add to axios